# What causes elevated liver function tests in a young asymptomatic patient?

Tags: blood-tests, liver

What are the possible causes and most probable causes of raised liver function tests (in particular AST and ALT) in an otherwise healthy, asymptomatic, young adult?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two important questions:

- Has AST/ALT elevation been present only once in blood sample?
- Is the elevation more than 3x the upper limit?

Basis for "normal" values should be understood. "Normal" values indicate confidence interval which includes 95% of healthy individuals. As so, any blood test with slightly elevated value may be normal, since all healthy individuals does not belong to the 95% confidence interval on which the "normal" values are based. As so you should not be automatically concerned if your blood level is above "normal".  Of course this does not imply that fact that you should refer to your GP for more information and further investigation.

Comment: The AST/ALT was raised on an initial test, and both were 3x more than upper limits of normal.  The GP noted this but ordered no further investigations.